# Preview webpage at mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, django, frontend

I am new to html. I'm currently using django to create a website and wondering is there some way that I can preview my website at phone? For instance, if I set my width to be 1000px, how this will behave in a mobile device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using google chrome, you can inspect the page (CTRL + SHIFT + I ) and then select the device icon in the upper left corner. This option will show you how your website will respond on mobile.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should build a responsive web application. Responsive Web design is the approach that suggests that design and development should respond to the user’s behaviour and environment based on screen size, platform and orientation.

The practice consists of a mix of flexible grids and layouts, images and an intelligent use of CSS media queries. As the user switches from their laptop to iPad, the website should automatically switch to accommodate for resolution, image size and scripting abilities.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Google Chrome dev-tools, but I find them woefully inadequate and often inaccurate. They don't render the site I am currently working on very well.

I would recommend using a tool like Ngrok. It can be used to let you host the development environment on your local machine while easily viewing the site on your mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I reccomend using frameworks like Bootstrap which make all your components on your page 100% responsive (components adjust to the display size automatically) if you want them to be.
When your testing your website on your browser, right click anywhere and select "inspect". You will be promted a viewing window where you can select the mobile device of your choice to emulatee your website on it. 
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tf96Z.png)